# MVC: Submit on TextBox change

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox on my MVC 4 view, and I would like to let the user press Enter on changing the text and call a controller's action method. Thanks.

Here is a part of my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="editor">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FolderPath)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FolderPath, new { @Id = "FolderPath", @style="width:500px;" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FolderPath)
    </div>
```

And a part of the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Refresh")]
public ActionResult Refresh(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(ediFileModel.FolderPath))
    {
        FolderPath = ediFileModel.FolderPath;
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("FolderPath", "This folder does not exist!");
    }
    ediFileModel = Load();
    return View("Index", ediFileModel);
}
```

Comment: -1. You should know the difference between client side and server side. Javascript is your friend

Comment: What is not working as you expected? What have you tried?

Comment: @MikeSW I know the difference, and I want to submit the form.

Comment: @DavidShochet Based on the things you wrote, you don't. You want to submit a form or do a refresh _from the browser_ (client side), yet your show us server side code and you tagged your question as c#, when it should have been javascript, html. It helps you to understand the techs you're using, it will simplify your work.

Comment: @MikeSW But to do the refresh, information from the server is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a submit button...

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

inside your form.

Comment: I have submit buttons, and they are responsible for different actions, but I thought it would be more convenient for the user just to press the Enter key. Otherwise, as I understand, the first submit button on the form is "pressed" when Enter is clicked, and it may be not the button I would like to be pressed on text change. E.g. the first button I have is Send, but I don't want to send anything on changing the text, I only want to refresh the form based on the entered text.